# Loop over Json using Golang go-simplejson

Tags: json, go

I am working in Golang,and using the package `github.com/bitly/go-simplejson`

I will receive a Json from the client side, I already constructed the json object using that package. Now I need to iterate over all the "first level" elements of that Json. The Json is something like this:

```
{"Name":"demo2","Creator":"some creator","URL":"www.url.com","GACode":"UA-xxxx"}
```

My code is:

```
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
settings,_ := simplejson.NewJson(body)
fmt.Printf("\nJson: %+v",settings)

for k, v := range settings.MustArray() {
    fmt.Println("\n k:",k)
    fmt.Println("\n v:",v)
}
```

When I print the Json I receive:

```
Json: &{data:map[Name:demo2 Creator:some creator URL:www.url.com GACode:UA-xxxx]}
```

And the loop is giving me nothing, MustArray() is giving me an empty array. The keys of that Json are very dynamic so I cannot do somehting like `.Get("TheKey")` because I don't know the name of the keys that can come in the json.

Then, how can I loop over that Json? I am more insterested in loop over the first level of that Json.

Comment: In Go you can loop over a map just like you loop over an array, instead of the `index, value` combo, you'll get `key, value` from `:= range map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go you can use the `range` loop to iterate over a `map` the same way you would over an `array` or `slice`. The values provided to you by the range loop on each iteration will be the map's keys and their corresponding values.

So you can simply change your loop line from:

```
for k, v := range settings.MustArray() {
```

To:

```
for k, v := range settings.MustMap() {
```

---

Also, personally, I would recommend ditching `simplejson` unless you have a better use case for it than what you have in your example. Using the standard `encoding/json` you can achieve the same result with less effort in my opinion.

```
var settings map[string]interface{}
if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&settings); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("\nJson: %+v",settings)

for k, v := range settings {
    fmt.Println("\n k:",k)
    fmt.Println("\n v:",v)
}
```

Example on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TKdO5pOJCY

More info on `for` with `range` here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range